# Why React doesn't know new elements is entering when child element doesn't have key props?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Below codes is for animating components.

1. Every 3 Seconds, I change `listItem` states
2. `AnimationText` re-rendered, so animation occurs

```
const AnimationText = styled.div`
    /* ... */
    animation: ${SlideUpAnimation} 750ms ease forwards;
`;

// this code works (success animate)
const BestCocktailList = () => {
    const [listItem, setListItem] = useState<BestCocktail[]>(...);
    const [itemIdx, setItemIdx] = useState<{ old: number; new: number }>(...); 

    useEffect(() => {
      // change state every 3 seconds
      setInterval(() => {
          setItemIdx((prev) => ({ old: prev.new, new: (prev.new + 1) % (listItem.length) }));
      }, 3000);
      // more codes..
    }, [listItem]);
    
    return (
      // ...
        <AnimationContainer>
          <AnimationText key={`o_${itemIdx.old}`}>
            {listItem[itemIdx.old].name}
          </AnimationText>
          <AnimationText key={`n_${itemIdx.new}`}>
            {listItem[itemIdx.new].name}
          </AnimationText>
        </AnimationContainer>
    );
}
```

I understood why above code works correctly. React knows the difference of element tree because of changing key props.

But I can't understand why below codes are not working.

```
// do not works (failed animate)
const BestCocktailList = () => {
// ...
    return (
        // ...
        <AnimationContainer>
          <AnimationText>
            {listItem[itemIdx.old].name}
          </AnimationText>
          <AnimationText>
            {listItem[itemIdx.new].name}
          </AnimationText>
        </AnimationContainer>
    );
}
```

The Difference is usage of key props.

```
// success
<AnimationText key={some key}/>

// fail
<AnimationText/>
```

if there is no key props, React looks from top to bottom for finding difference (just my knowledge). And it is obiously different element I think (like below)!

```
// before
[
  { type: 'div', props: { children: listItem[0].name }},
  { type: 'div', props: { children: listItem[1].name }}
]

// after
[
  { type: 'div', props: { children: listItem[1].name }},
  { type: 'div', props: { children: listItem[2].name }}
]
```

Then why animation not working?

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (please note both the "minimal" **and** the "reproducible" :-) ), ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). I wouldn't expect keys to be important there.